# Broadband coverage GIF image layer needs to be selectable (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, intersection, select-by-location

I am working on a project on Arcmap where I have 80,000 co-ordinates of postcodes and a broadband coverage map. I need to know which of the co-ordinates intersect with the coverage map.

I have added the coverage map in GIF format and it is a non-selectable layer. I need this layer to be selectable so that I can use 'select by location' and figure out which co-ordinates intersect it.

My project is very similar to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thWDMCG24cc).

I just need the Broadband coverage GIF layer to be selectable.

Does anyone know how to do this? or can you explain a better way to go about solving this project.

Comment: How extensive is the analysis, i.e. will you repeat the interrogation of the map a few times, once, automatically?  Also, most types of analysis like this are done where the boundary layer is a vector, your gif layer is a raster. You might like to look at converting the raster to a vector which will be simpler if the image has distinct features and colours.

Comment: Definitely interested in answers to this.